# Критические секции Delphi

Tags: delphi

У меня проблема с критическими секциями в Delphi XE3. Подозреваю, что они вообще не работают, потому что что с ними, что без них. Задача переместить все строки из Memo1 в Memo2 используя 4 (!) потока последовательно и без повторений.

Нужно получить вот это:

```html
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    42
    r
    fe
    g
    ad
    a
    sd
    asd
    as
    d
    ad
    as
    d
    al;kl
    a
    g
    jk
    jl
```

Получаю вот это:

```html
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
42
r
fe
g
ad
a
sd
asd
as
d
ad
as
d
al;kl
a
g
jk
jl

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
42
r
fe
g
ad
a
sd
asd
as
d
ad
as
d
al;kl
a
g
jk
jl

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
42
r
fe
g
ad
a
sd
asd
as
d
ad
as
d
al;kl
a
g
jk
jl

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
42
r
fe
g
ad
a
sd
asd
as
d
ad
as
d
al;kl
a
g
jk
jl

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
42
r
fe
g
ad
a
sd
asd
as
d
ad
as
d
al;kl
a
g
jk
jl
```

Что мне сделать?

Код:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, syncobjs, Vcl.StdCtrls, sMemo, sButton;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    sButton1: TsButton;
    sMemo1: TsMemo;
    sMemo2: TsMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

 type
  Rain = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure Sync;
  protected
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  CS:TCriticalSection;
  Li:TStringList;
  Work: boolean;
  a,b:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor Rain.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure Rain.Execute;
begin
  while work do begin
    cs.Enter;
    inc(a);
    if a<Li.Count then b:=a else Work:=False;
    synchronize(Sync);
    Cs.Leave;    
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CS:=TCriticalSection.Create;
  Li:=TStringlist.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Work:=True;
  A:=-1;
  LI.Add(sMemo1.Lines.Text);
  for I := 1 to 4 do
    Rain.Create(False);
end;

procedure Rain.Sync;
begin
  Form1.sMemo2.Lines.Add(Li.Strings[b]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: С Memo (и любым другим GUI) нельзя работать из потоков, поэтому не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться засинхронизировав 4 потока? По коду: у вас обращение к переменной `b` вынесено за критическую секцию. Перенесите вызов `synchronize(Sync);` внутрь критической секции.

Comment: Как была поставлена реальная задача? В текущей формулировке она не имеет никакого смысла по указанным zed причинам.

Comment: Перенос synchronize не помог. Если использовать TStringlist.count, то происходит примерно то же самое. Дело не в мемо, а в какой-то другой херне, а вот в какой я понять не могу, ткните носом пожалуйста.

Comment: Вероятно, у меня битый делфяк с битыми критическими секциями, потому что я уже ранее их реализовывал на другом компьютере и всё было отлично и работало как часы -__-

Comment: Реальная задача такова:  Нужно инкрементировать значение переменной типа Integer, затем сравнить не больше ли она количества строк в файле, который заранее загружен в TStringlist. Дальше продолжить выполнение программы, всё по аналогии, но ни тут ни там нихрена не работает

Comment: UPD: Изменил Memo на TSTringList, теперь всё то же самое, только "if a<Li.Count then b:=a else Work:=False;" Теперь выводится один и тот же текст, но только 4 раза подряд. Что это может быть?

Comment: Ещё `if` в критической секции надо переписать, чтобы `synchronize(Sync)` вызывалась только когда `a<Li.Count`.

Comment: Zed, Спасибо большое, именно в этом и была моя ошибка. Конкретно в вызове synchronize

Что странно, ведь раньше всё именно так работало. Ужас. Ты сделал мой день, чел)