# Критические секции Delphi. Не могу разобраться

Tags: delphi

ребят, не могу разобраться с критическими секциями. Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно из списка TStringList вывести в Memo все строки по порядку в несколько потоков.

Пример:

Загружаю вот это:

```
119.15.95.182:8888
37.233.85.155:53281
45.222.96.12:30135
103.68.0.115:47390
46.105.57.149:36695
142.165.167.117:53281
103.19.37.24:53281
185.132.173.18:41258
195.91.132.20:19600
43.252.158.107:8080
101.255.74.62:34691
180.250.16.66:53281
45.4.91.132:32299
150.242.180.151:80
103.87.76.106:43262
185.228.119.237:39686
103.213.237.46:83
131.161.26.90:8080
203.130.208.165:8081
```

Получаю вот это:

```
37.233.85.155:53281
37.233.85.155:53281
103.68.0.115:47390
103.68.0.115:47390
142.165.167.117:53281
142.165.167.117:53281
185.132.173.18:41258
185.132.173.18:41258
43.252.158.107:8080
43.252.158.107:8080
180.250.16.66:53281
180.250.16.66:53281
150.242.180.151:80
150.242.180.151:80
185.228.119.237:39686
185.228.119.237:39686
131.161.26.90:8080
131.161.26.90:8080
203.130.208.165:8081
```

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, sMemo, sDialogs, sEdit,
  sSpinEdit, sButton, SyncObjs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    sButton1: TsButton;
    sButton2: TsButton;
    sSpinEdit1: TsSpinEdit;
    sOpenDialog1: TsOpenDialog;
    sMemo1: TsMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  type
  MyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure Sync;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  TN, St, StNum:integer;
  Lister: TStringlist;
  CS: TCriticalSection;
  Work: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Lister:=TSTringList.Create;
  CS:= TCRiticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if sOpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    Lister.LoadFromFile(sOpenDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.sButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Work:=True;
  St:=-1;
   for TN := 1 to strtoint(sSpinEdit1.Text) do MyThread.Create(False);

end;

{ MyThread }

constructor MyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
while work do begin

  cs.Enter;
     inc(st);
     if st<Lister.Count then StNum:=St else Work:=False;
  cs.Leave;

    if work then begin
       Synchronize(Sync);
    end;

end;
end;

procedure MyThread.Sync;
begin
  Form1.sMemo1.Lines.Add(Lister.Strings[StNum]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: "по порядку в несколько потоков" как то несовместимы понятия =) потоки для того и нужны чтобы работа выполнялась не линейно а параллельно =)

Comment: Ну для этого же и есть критические секции и синхронизация, что бы один поток занимался одним значением переменной

Comment: Ошибки всё те же, что и в вашем прошлом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887369 (доступ к переменной `StNum` вне критической секции). Два раза на те же грабли?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Критические секции Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887369/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-delphi)

Comment: @moze.code, да именно так, но если у вас задача в простом выводе(без долгой\сложной обработки) - то смысл потоков теряется и получаем только лишний тормоз

Comment: Там с обработкой, но я не стал её включать в задачу на сайт, потому что это было бы долго читать

Comment: Zed, Это подобный вопрос, но чёт не выходит нифига, а добавлять synchronize в критическую секцию как-то не особо мне нравится этот вариант (не знаю почему)

Comment: @moze.code, может стоит пойти другим путём? сначало свести в массив\списко\иную структуру - в том порядке в котором обработали, а потом отсортировать и вывести в нужном порядке? (добавить в структуру - позицию)

Comment: Суть не в том, что нужно отсортировать, а обработать все строки в файле без дубликатов, посмотрите внимательно пример (Это тест при двух потоках)

Comment: В таком случае, сделайте `StNum` приватной переменной потока - тогда вы сможете обращаться к ней безопасно вне критической секции. Да и переменную `work` надо переносить туда же.

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: "Суть не в том, что нужно отсортировать, а обработать все строки в файле без дубликатов" Вот этого в вашем изначальном описании небыло от слова совсем =) вы пытаетесь снова и снова использовать линейные алгоритмы в потоках, ошибка в этом =) мой вам совет, сделайте свою архитектуру немного иначе =) посмотрите в сторону паттерна "наблюдатель" по текущему описанию задачи именно он вам и нужен, либо задайте вопрос с полностью сформулированной задачей, попробую подсказать паттерн.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обращаться к переменной `StNum` вне критической секции, её надо сделать приватной:

```
type
  MyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FStNum: Integer;
    procedure Sync;
  ...
  end;

...

procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    cs.Enter;
    try
      Inc(st);
      if st >= Lister.Count then begin
        Break;
      end; 
      FStNum := St;
    finally 
      cs.Leave;
    end;

    // здесь можно делать какую-то длительную работу

    Synchronize(Sync);
  end;
end;

procedure MyThread.Sync;
begin
  Form1.sMemo1.Lines.Add(Lister.Strings[FStNum]);
end;
```

А если внутри критической секции больше ничего не происходит и она нужна только для доступа к переменной `st` (а `Lister` не изменяется со временем), то её можно заменить на Interlocked функцию:

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
var
  VСount: Integer;
begin
  VCount := Lister.Count;

  while not Terminated do begin
    FStNum := InterlockedIncrement(St);
    if FStNum >= VCount then begin
      Break;
    end;     

    // ...

    Synchronize(Sync);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: То, что нужно, благодарю!